# HTTP.call throws errors instead of returning response

Tags: meteor

I am working with the Facebook graph API and have run into trouble regarding handling failed requests.

I use this code to create a new post

```
SocialFacebook.createPosting = function(data) {
  var options = {
    params: {
      access_token : data.tokens.accessToken,
      message      : data.text
    }
  };

  var url      = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + data.graphId + '/feed';
  var response = HTTP.call('POST', url, options).data;
  return response;
}
```

But instead of returning a JS object with error information in the response, it throws an error on failed requests

```
Exception while invoking method 'createPosting' Error: failed [500] {"error":{"message":"Duplicate status message","type":"FacebookApiException","code":506,"error_subcode":1455006,"is_transient":false,"error_user_title":"Duplicate Status Update","error_user_msg":"This status update is identical to the last one you posted. Try posting something different, or delete your previous update."}}
```

Because it's wrapped in an `Error`, the otherwise JSON object is now a string with some other stuff appended to it, which makes it difficult to parse and extract the attributes

Any idea as to why it throws an error, instead of returning a JS object with error details like usually?

Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

[According to the docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/http_call), about `HTTP.call()`:

> On the server, this function can be run either synchronously or asynchronously. If the callback is omitted, it runs synchronously and the results are returned once the request completes successfully. If the request was not successful, an error is thrown.

So there you have it: since you called `HTTP.call()` synchronously (without providing a callback), if it responds with an error (in your case, `Code 500`) the error is thrown and not included in the data.

Comment: Ah I see, so I suppose the only way to get the JSON error is to wrap the request in a wrapAsync/runSync ?

Comment: Yes, that is one way I guess, or you could try using `try` / `catch` around your `HTTP.call()` statement?

Comment: Yeah, but then I'll still have to manually cut/parse the string

Comment: I'm pretty sure you will get an object in the catch argument, not a string.

Comment: Yes i get the error object, with the `message` method. However, this method returns the otherwise JSON response object as a string

Comment: Then just parse it using `JSON.parse(error.message)`? I'm afraid I don't see another way

Comment: Problem is the string also contains `failed [500]` in the beginning, and it seems awfully hacky if i have to substring that out

Comment: Oh I see ; yeah that doesn't sound good indeed then. Well then either try to see if the object is stored somewhere else in the error object, if not... You're left checking which of the two (Meteor or Facebook API) stores their errors like a donkey and look for how other users dealt with it.